# Using Neo4j Testcontainers With Grails and Spock, can't find correct neo4j datasource

Tags: java, spring, testing, grails, neo4j

I'm using testcontainer to test the neo4j-related functionalities in the application with Grails 3.3.2 and Spock.

The grails application config for Neo4j:

```
environments {
   development {
    grails {
        neo4j {
            url="bolt://dev-host:7687"
            username='xxx'
            password='xxx'
        }
    }
}
```

The setup for Neo4j Spock integration test

```
@Testcontainers
class Test extends Specification {
    static Neo4jContainer<?> container = new Neo4jContainer<>("neo4j:3.5")
            .withoutAuthentication()

    void setupSpec() {
        container.start()
        System.setProperty("grails.neo4j.url", container.getBoltUrl())
    }
    
    void "1. test something"() {neo4jService.save(dummyData)}

}
```

I have to change the application property source during the container setup so that the neo4j driver can find the correct database. In Spring/SpringBoot, we can use `@DynamicPropertySource`. However, in Grails, I have to set the property manually.

**Current Problem:**

Only when I don't have any neo4j configs in the application config, the test can find the right URL created by the testcontainer. If I use the config above, even though I set the system property and let it point to the testcontainer, the test is still going to use the `bolt://dev-host:7687` defined in the config file.

Any idea on this? Thanks a lot.